# setting a global javascript variable

Tags: jquery, var, bxslider

I am currently working with bxslider, here is my setup:

```
$('.bxslider').bxSlider({
minSlides: 3,
  maxSlides: 4,
  slideWidth: 350,
  slideMargin: 10,
  startSlide: numItems});
```

i am trying to set the numItems like this:

```
var numItems = $('.bx-pager-item').length
```

when i alert the numItems out, it works fine.

The var needs to be after the bxslider code becuase it needs to wait for the slider to finish loading.

The issue i have is that i cannot use the var in the bxslider variables at the top, as it is declared below it.

Im fairly new to javascript, so any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you could move the last image to the first position?

Comment: You can't load the slider with an option that is set after the slider is loaded, it goes against newtons third law  of motion ?